# Does the power of the resistor change when the battery is changed?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage, power

Wanted to know whether the changing of a battery (potential difference)affects the change of power consumption of  a resistor of a bulb.
please tell me how the change will occur?

Comment: For most loads the power consumption will increase with the battery voltage. For an ohmic resistor it will be given by $P=U^2/R$, but lightbulbs are not ohmic resistors.

Comment: @CuriousOne then what's they?

Comment: What are lightbulbs? PTCs = positive temperature coefficient resistors.

Answer (score 0):

If resistor is an ohmic one, on applying a higher volt battery, power will increase as power for a resistor is $V^2/r$. If it is non ohmic one, the answer may depend upon other factors as well.